# Let G be a group, and H is a subgroup. The number of elements of H is half of the number of elements of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a group, and H is a subgroup. The number of elements of H is half of the number of elements of G. Let x in G and the order of x is 3. Show x in H.

Thanks

Comment: $H$ is normal, think about $\bar{x}$ in $G/H$

Answer (score 4):

Since $|H| = (1/2)|G|$, $H$ has index $2$ in $G$, so $H$ is normal in $G$ and we may consider the factor group $G/H$. Since $x$ has order $3$, $(xH)^3 = x^3H = H$. So the order of $xH$ divides $3$. Its order cannot be three since $G/H$ has order $2$. Therefore $xH$ has order 1, which means $xH = H$, i.e., $x\in H$.